# How to ask "What is your opinion on X thing/X person?"

Tags: grammar, translation, phrases, english-to-japanese, phrase-requests

As the title says. How do you ask for someone's opinion on something in Japanese?

My Japanese tutor says than an easy way to do this can be

> 「Xはどうですか？」

thus saying

> "How about X,"

but I was curious if there were any other phrases, sentence structures, etc. in Japanese that also communicates

> "What's your opinion on X?"

And, if there are, in what contexts or situations are they supposed to be used in?

Answer (score 1):

So you could produce very direct translations involving the Japanese word for opinion, but I don't think that's what you're asking for. If what you're looking for is a natural, easy way to express English sentiments like `what's your opinion on ~~?` or most relevantly `what do you think about ~~?`, the phrase you want is probably [をどう思う](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%92%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86). The link includes plenty of example sentences, but this an everyday phrase for asking people broadly what they think/feel about something, without suggesting it to them.

Edit: just to be clear, `~~はどうですか？` and similar structures can take on meanings of suggestion much like the English translation you provided, `how about ~~`.